# Gitweb: how to only list the git repositories and nothing else (like log, shortlog, summary, tree)?

Tags: git, gitolite, gitweb

I have gitweb correctly displaying all the git repositories in the gitolite server. But I want to completely exclude the options to look at logs, summary, shortlogs from the web view.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Out of curiosity... why do you want to exclude those options?

Comment: We are just starting to setup our gitserver and have not established proper permission systems yet. Right now, disparate teams can nose into other team's code. Some of our developers don't like that wide-openness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know a direct way to achieve that kind of filtering.
One way would be to tinker with [`gitweb.perl`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/gitweb/gitweb.perl) content, but that would be a custom-made solution only.
And that would be valid for gitweb used with or without gitolite (ie using gitolite doesn't matter for that filter).

Comment: Thanks. It was in gitweb.perl.